# Hacer un Reporte pie Chart en javascript estoy utilizando java jsp con mysql

Tags: javascript, java, mysql

Quiero hacer un reporte circular de cuantos femeninos y masculinos tengo en mi tabla.

Este es el resultado de mi script:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL, SUM(CASE WHEN SEXO = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 
MASCULINOS, SUM(CASE WHEN SEXO = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FEMENINOS FROM PERSONA
```

[image: Resultado de mis SQL]

En Javascript tengo lo siguiente :

```
var ctx2 = document.getElementById("pieChart").getContext('2d');
    var pieChart = new Chart(ctx2, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                    data: [12, 19],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)'
                    ],
                    label: 'Dataset 1'
                }],
            labels: [
                "Red",
                "Orange"
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true
        }

    });
```

Comment: Y cuál es el error o qué no logras visualizar?

Comment: Cómo insertar la consulta en Javascript